# How to handle LIS Contention in web socket application?

Tags: c#, websocket

LIS application using web socket c#
I am working on an application which receive Query Record message from LIS machine and reply with required test but most of time contention occurred. This contention occurs because machine want to communicate at the same time. now if i am going to let application it's process my reply becomes idle. so i want help how to handle contention.?